# Mockery equivalent of PHPUnits, returnValueMap

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, mockery

I have just started using [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) in place of PHPUnits own mocking features.

Does Mockery have an equivalent of PHPUnits [returnValueMap](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php), where it can return a specific value based on specific argument values supplied to the method call?

This is how it is done with PHPUnit.

```
<?php

$stub = $this->createMock(SomeClass::class);

$map = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
];

$stub->method('doSomething')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));

$this->assertEquals('d', $stub->doSomething('a', 'b', 'c'));
$this->assertEquals('h', $stub->doSomething('e', 'f', 'g'));
```

Answer (score 0):

My question is a bit of "duh" moment for myself.  This is the Mockery equivalent of using `returnValueMap()` in PHPUnit:

```
<?php

$stub = \Mockery::mock(SomeClass::class);

$stub->shouldReceive('doSomething')->with('a', 'b', 'c')->andReturn('d');
$stub->shouldReceive('doSomething')->with('e', 'f', 'g')->andReturn('h');

$this->assertEquals('d', $stub->doSomething('a', 'b', 'c'));
$this->assertEquals('h', $stub->doSomething('e', 'f', 'g'));
```

... duh.